# MailSystem.Net IMAP problem getting Email body

Tags: .net, email, imap

I'm using the MailSystem.NET IMAP functionality to retrieve E-mail.

Connecting and login succeed and I see there are 4 messages on the server.
When I retrieve the messages I can read the subject, from/to etc. However, when I read the Email body only a fraction of the body is displayed.

```
Message msg = inbox.Fetch.MessageObject(i);
Console.WriteLine(msg.BodyHtml.Text);
```

The code above will display:

```
<!DOCTYPE
```

How can I get the complete content of the E-mail body? (Also asked on [CodePlex](http://mailsystem.codeplex.com), but there is not a lot of activity there).

Regards,

Michel

Comment: What does the fraction look like? What do you get if you use something like `BodyPlainText` (if there is any)?

Comment: msg.BodyText.Text is an empty string.
I will add the fraction to my question.

Comment: Can you examine (and post) real raw contents of the message in a mail client? Looks to me like a bug in the library.

Answer (score 0):

[Issues with IMAP](http://mailsystem.codeplex.com/discussions/242692) might help with your quest.

Answer (score 0):

I use a different library now, but when I checked codeplex an answer was provided:

*This seems to be the result of last change http://mailsystem.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/changes/59386.
I do not know what is the reason of this change, but it seems to be absolute non logical.
If you remove it from your source code, the system would work fine.*

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Message mailMsg = mailbox.Fetch.MessageObject(i);
string mailBodyContent = system.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mailMsg.OriginalData);
Console.WriteLine(mailBodyContent);
```

This will return the entire mail body.